# Unable to edit CMS pages in magento 2.1.3

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1.3

I am unable to edit cms pages in magento 2.1.3. When clicked on edit, it shows blank page. What could be causing it.

Comment: Right click on the page, inspect, check the console for errors?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I'd look at is to make sure that the WYWIWYG editor is actually enabled for the Magento 2 site.  (Sometimes it's not, depending on the developer who installed it.)

You'll want to go to: 
**Stores >>> Configuration >> Content Management**:
[image: HTML editor - turned on or off?]

If that's on, then likely you have a server configuration issue (file permissions are incorrect, or file ownership needs to be changed), or the installation has missing files.

Last thing - if you're not using an up-to-date browser, the WYWIWYG editor may not work as well.